# SQL Integrity Concern for long running staged Backend Processing

Tags: sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I have an application which selects quite a large amount of data (pyodbc + sqlalchemy, db = SQL Server), does some operations on it (with pandas) and then inserts the results into another table.

My issue is now that I would like to mark the rows which I have selected originally at the end of my processing.

What is the best way to achieve this?

- I currently prevent any new inserts etc to my first table with a pid lock (blocking the loader), but this of course is not a constraint on the DB and then bulk update the rows in the first table which don't have any mark yet
- I could of course get a list of the ID's which were in my original data and update the ID's in batches which is probably really slow since there could be millions upon millions of rows)
- Another option would be to lock the table at the start of my process, but is this actually a good idea? (what if my script dies to whatever reasons during the processing in a way that the "finally" block for releasing the lock is not executed)

Thankful for any ideas, thoughts etc!

Comment: "best" cannot be measured. "Best" for your situation may not be "best" for anyone else. The better question is - what problem are you trying to solve? If you have no problem, then stop trying to fix something that isn't broken. Seems your process should know which rows are involved - why is it so difficult to "mark" them at the end? Why would you need to "get a list" for rows that you have already retrieved? Suggest you first research "pessimistic locking"

Comment: Instead of marking the source rows at the end of the process you might consider marking them at the beginning of the process using a tag that uniquely identifies that particular processing run (e.g. 'MachineID_yyyy_mm_dd_hh_nn_ss'). That way you wouldn't have to worry about new rows being added, or doing any locking, or other nuisances. If for whatever reason your process fails then you can go back and "unmark" the rows using that same unique batch identifier.